Child younger than his father (Synthetical A Priori or A Posteriori)
The proposition "A child is younger than his father" is a posteriori or synthetical a priori?
I think it should be synthetical a priori because the concept "father" means someone who causes his child to be born. If "father" is the cause of the existence of the child, then since we know whatever causes is the first / before, then "father" has to be before "child". Kant himself takes "cause-and-effect principle" as a synthetical a priori to perceive everything in this frame.

If the father travels at relativistic speeds, relative to their child, the child can indeed become the older of the two.

The conclusion presupposes empirical facts about biological aging and physical causality (uniform aging, unavailability of rejuvenation, absence of time loops), so it cannot be a priori.

Synthetic a priori is a trademark of Kant which is the most interesting within his combinations, therefore your concerned proposition which is obviously uninteresting must not be synthetic a priori at least per Kant...

You are likely to get different answers to this question, because not everyone agrees on the meaning of the various distinctions, analytic/synthetic, a priori/a posteriori, and necessary/contingent. Here's mine.
There is no absolute sense in which any proposition is necessarily true, a priori knowable, or even analytic. A proposition may be necessary relative to some assumptions, i.e. it follows by necessity from those assumptions. A proposition may be a priori knowable relative to some assumptions. A proposition may be analytic relative to the acceptance of some definitions and some logic.
So to ask of some proposition, is it synthetic a priori or a posteriori simply invites the response: relative to what assumptions? If a man impregnates a woman and she builds a time machine and travels back to an earlier time before the man was born and gives birth, then the child is born at an earlier date than the father. Does that make the child older? It depends on your definition of age. If time travel is possible then our concepts and definitions surrounding age will have to change.
If a man fathers a child and goes into hibernation for many years, is he younger than his child? He may have biologically aged less. Again, it depends on your definition. If a man fathers a child and goes off on a space mission and orbits a black hole and returns, is he younger than his child because less time has passed for him? Whose reference frame are we supposed to use?
The answer to all these questions depends on our best understanding of scientific theories and on whatever defintions those theories include. As such they are all a posteriori in absolute terms and they are all revisable in the light of experience.
Any question of this kind is going to depend on what assumptions and definitions we are willing to accept. Even propositions that some people will tell you are anaytic are still revisable in the light of experience because definitions can change when we revise our theories. So at the end of the day the question is completely unimportant and pointless.

Concerning the use of these concepts by Kant:
As soon as one understands the meaning of the two terms "father" and "child" one can conclude that a child is younger than his father.
Hence the proposition "A child is younger than his father" is an analytical statement. Like all analytical statements it is a priori: One does not need any empirical test for verification.

But doesn't it important "how" the meanings of concepts are defined? Why I'm asking this is because the word "child" and "father" and their relationship are defined by biological and social observation. We observed human being and two people being in love, labelled the man "father" and the woman "mother" when they have a baby that we labelled "child". These concepts are defined empirically, I think on the other hand.
After learning the meaning, I can answer many things too.
"Apple is a fruit"
Is this a priori or posteriori?
When I understand the meaning of "apple", I directly answer.

@Jawel7 Your original question does no problematize the definition of the terms “father”, “child”, “younger”. The meaning of these terms is obvious. You ask instead a question from epistemology: How to determine the truth of the proposition “A child is younger than his father”? My answer: Just analyze the meaning of all terms involved in the proposition. You don’t need any empiricism.

I understand your point but there's another point confusing me here. How do we get those definitions? They are defined by observation. Why I see it as important because then "Sun emits heat energy" should be a priori too. After understanding concepts, many things can be a priori even though they belong to the external world.

@Jawel7 If you define the sun as the yellow body on the sky which seems to rise and to set each day, it is not at all clear, that the sun emits energy in form of heat. Even if you define the sun as the gravitational center of our planetary system. The heat-production and heat-emission of the sun is a deep result of science, epistemological a synthetical a-posteriori.

Then what about "Apple is a fruit" ? A priori or a posteriori ? It's basically defined based on empirical data, but meriam webster dictionary accepts it as a priori.

@Jawel7 One usually names apples even as an example to explain what is meant by the word "fruit". Hence one defines the word "fruit" in such a way that it comprises apples: "Apples are fruits" is an analytical statement, hence a priori.

I see, thank you. Then with the same logic, can we also know historical things as a priori? "Great Alexander was born in 356 BC." is a priori or a posteriori? I think it's also a priori because to justify it, I can't go to the external world. Great Alexander is defined in history classes with some important personal info, one of which is being born in 356 BC. Is that correct?
